# How long does it take for a new FIR to be created by ICAO

Tags: icao, air-traffic-management

How long does it take ICAO to create/approve a new Flight Information Region(FIR)?

Occasionally FIRs are split because of various reasons. The question is how long ICAO takes to approve the new FIRs creation.